# Textbox decimal validation - omit dots

Tags: c#, wpf, decimal

I'm doing a validation on TextBox where user must enter valid decimal text. Decimal represents amount of money.

Some examples of correct inputs:

```
1
1.000,99
1,99
1.000.000,99 etc.
```

Some examples of non-valid inputs:

```
1.0.0.0.0.
1.......0.0.0. etc.
```

Here is my validation code with TryParse method which I thought would solve everything:

```
   public void Validate_amount(string property_name, string string_value)
   {
        DeleteErrors(property_name);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string_value))//Ignore empty text
        {
            return;
        }
 
        bool is_amount = decimal.TryParse(string_value, out decimal n);
          
        if (!is_amount)
        {
            AddError(property_name, "Amount not correct");
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }
   }
```

Problem with this approach is that even examples of non-valid inputs are returned as True by TryParse method.

I can write as many of dots I like, and TryParse will allways return true. Comma however works as expected - only one is allowed.

How to fix this?

Comment: `decimal.TryParse(string_value, out double n)` - You're definitely *not* doing that because `decimal.TryParse` requires a `decimal` output parameter. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @madreflection, sorry, that was just a typo. I was trying with double too.

Comment: That's fine, but the [mre] request is still in play. Provide a simple program that passes a string literal to `decimal.TryParse` and returns `true` when you think it shouldn't. Keep in mind that not specifying a `CultureInfo` will result in variations in what you and others experience.

Comment: @madreflection, my complete code for validation is now posted. Not that It would be needed, IMO. Only TryParse method is where my problem occurs. An I tried with CultureInfo &  NumberStyles too, but so far didn't get expected results.

Comment: The only thing you need for a [mre] is a new console program with `Main` and one line in it, a call to `decimal.TryParse` that passes a string literal. That's something someone can try and validate.

Comment: Anyway, .NET allows the digit separator to be used for any grouping of digits, not just to separate thousands. If you need more stringent format validation, you'll need to do that yourself, such as with a regex.

Comment: @madreflection, I was hoping you won't say something like that. So I'm left only with Regex?

Comment: Stricly speaking, no, but it's probably going to be the easiest way to get past this problem, assuming it doesn't introduce other problems (you know the old saying...). Ask yourself critically, though, *"do I really need to restrict the input so narrowly?"* And if the answer really is "yes", follow that with *"do I need to do that* now *or can it wait until I've fried the bigger fish?"*

Comment: @madreflection, yes I need to. Problem is that this is being saved in Oracle. And our users are pretty much doing typo mistakes every day. Though, interesting is that "1.0.0." gets inserted as "100". So It's a valid decimal in every way.

Answer (score 0):

The TryParse method has a complete signature like this: `TryParse (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Decimal)`.

When you do not specify the 2nd and 3rd parameters, the default value is used for them.
For your example, the complete call will look like this:

```
bool is_amount = decimal.TryParse(
    string_value, 
    NumberStyles.Number, 
    NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, 
    out decimal n);
```

The number of digits in groups is set in the NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyGroupSizes property (int []).
And it depends on the OS settings.
Let's say, on my computer, your incorrect examples all return false.

You can make a copy of the current value, change the properties you need and pass this instance to TryParse:

```
string string_value = "1.0.0.0.0.";

NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo) NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();

Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSizes));

numberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 };

Debug.WriteLine(decimal.TryParse(string_value, NumberStyles.Number, numberFormatInfo, out decimal number));
```